# Install Maven itself from Maven Central

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a maven plugin I would like to test against different Maven versions (Ex.: 2.2.1 & 3.0.4). Ideally I don't want users running the build to have to install these exact versions manually.

Is it possible to install specific versions of Maven itself from Maven Central or some other source that would then cache them in the local Maven repo for subsequent builds?

Comment: You could use the "install-file" plugins to upload the various Maven releases into you local repository. Better again would be to deploy your own Maven repository using Nexus (or Archiva...). But at the end of the day I think @carlspring is right. This would be simplest done as a set of CI jobs running on something like Jenkins. All your platorm tests could then be automatically triggered to run quietly in the background, every time you commit changes.

Comment: Just to clarify: My goal is to have the build fully reproducible on all machines, not just the CI server, with minimal installation effort. Ideally it should be a matter or checking out from scm and running the build with whatever mvn version you have. Not unlike the gradle wrapper concept...

Comment: Understood, but isn't this a bookstrap problem? You need Maven to install Maven, so that you can run Maven..... As you've correctly pointed out, Gradle provides a solution to this via it's wrapper... Grails also provides mechanisms for bootstapping itself from ANT/ivy and Maven. Problem is these mechanisms are mostly broken now that Grails is better supported. This might eventually happen with Gradle, time will tell....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven distributions are stored in Maven Central Repository, as you can see here:

- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/apache-maven
- https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.apache.maven~apache-maven~~~~kw,versionexpand

Therefore, it can be used as a normal dependency with following coordinates:

tar.gz variant:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <classifier>bin</classifier>
    <type>tar.gz</type>
</dependency>
```

zip variant:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <classifier>bin</classifier>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

The rest is quite standard - you will probably use it in integration test poms, and call them with [maven-invoker-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin) as recommended by @khmarbaise.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply just install a Continuous Integration (CI) server such as Jenkins / Hudson / TeamCity / etc? CI servers allow you to run your build against different versions of an SDK.

If your plugin is OSS (and on GitHub), I believe you can get free Jenkins hosting from [Cloudbees](http://www.cloudbees.com).

Downloading Maven itself from Maven Central is not possible. You can only download it from their site.

Comment: I already use Jenkins on the CI server. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a thing like the following:

```
   <profile>
      <id>run-its</id>
      <build>
        <!--  Download the different Maven versions -->
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>download-maven-2.0.11</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>download-single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/</url>
                  <fromFile>apache-maven-2.0.11-bin.tar.gz</fromFile>
                  <toDir>${project.build.directory}/maven/download/</toDir>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>download-maven-2.2.1</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>download-single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/</url>
                  <fromFile>apache-maven-2.2.1-bin.tar.gz</fromFile>
                  <toDir>${project.build.directory}/maven/download/</toDir>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>download-maven-3.0.3</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>download-single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/binaries/</url>
                  <fromFile>apache-maven-3.0.3-bin.tar.gz</fromFile>
                  <toDir>${project.build.directory}/maven/download/</toDir>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>


          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-4</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>extract-maven-2.0.11</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <fileset>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/maven/download/apache-maven-2.0.11-bin.tar.gz</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/maven/tools/</outputDirectory>
                  </fileset>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>extract-maven-2.2.1</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <fileset>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/maven/download/apache-maven-2.2.1-bin.tar.gz</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/maven/tools/</outputDirectory>
                  </fileset>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>extract-maven-3.0.3</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <fileset>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/maven/download/apache-maven-3.0.3-bin.tar.gz</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/maven/tools/</outputDirectory>
                  </fileset>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>

          <!--
            This is currently needed due to a bug of the truezip-plugin cause it unpacks without permission!
            see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-1796
           -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>chmod-files</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <target>
                      <chmod file="${project.build.directory}/maven/tools/apache-maven-2.0.11/bin/mvn" perm="+x"/>
                      <chmod file="${project.build.directory}/maven/tools/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/mvn" perm="+x"/>
                      <chmod file="${project.build.directory}/maven/tools/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin/mvn" perm="+x"/>
                    </target>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>

          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.4</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
              <debug>false</debug>
                  <!-- src/it-ip as for integration tests invoker plugin for the time of transition to maven-invoker-plugin -->
              <projectsDirectory>src/it</projectsDirectory>
              <showVersion>true</showVersion>
              <pomIncludes>
                <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
              </pomIncludes>
              <preBuildHookScript>setup</preBuildHookScript>
              <postBuildHookScript>verify</postBuildHookScript>
              <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>integration-test-maven-2.0.11</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>install</goal>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/invoker-reports-2.0.11</reportsDirectory>
                  <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo-2.0.11</localRepositoryPath>
                  <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it-2.0.11</cloneProjectsTo>
                  <mavenHome>${project.build.directory}/maven/tools/apache-maven-2.0.11</mavenHome>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>clean</goal>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                  </goals>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>integration-test-maven-2.2.1</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>install</goal>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/invoker-reports-2.2.1</reportsDirectory>
                  <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo-2.2.1</localRepositoryPath>
                  <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it-2.2.1</cloneProjectsTo>
                  <mavenHome>${project.build.directory}/maven/tools/apache-maven-2.2.1</mavenHome>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>clean</goal>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                  </goals>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>integration-test-maven-3.0.3</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>install</goal>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/invoker-reports-3.0.3</reportsDirectory>
                  <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo-3.0.3</localRepositoryPath>
                  <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it-3.0.3</cloneProjectsTo>
                  <mavenHome>${project.build.directory}/maven/tools/apache-maven-3.0.3</mavenHome>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>clean</goal>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                  </goals>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

This will download the different Maven version unpack the .tar.gz archives and make mvn executable and use [maven-invoker-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/) to run all integration test with these different maven versions.

**BUT** i can't recommend that. The better way is to use a CI solution (as already mentioned) which contains the different installations of Maven. Than you can run the integration tests for each Maven version separately.

Comment: What a monster snippet! +1 for not recommending it!